# Some problems with sorting in a simple Python code

Tags: python

The program should ask how many pounds of fruit there are for each type. The program should then display the information in the form fruit, weight listed in alphabetical order, one fruit type per line as shown below,
Apple, 6 lbs.
Banana, 11 lbs.
I have written the code this way but I couldn't figure out how to sort and display as it shown in the question:

```
fruit_list = []
empty_str = ''
print('Enter type of fruit, and how many pounds of each type there are')
print('(hit return when done)\n')
entered_fruit = input('Enter fruit: ')
while entered_fruit != empty_str:
    num_pounds = int(input('Enter number of pounds of ' + entered_fruit + ': '))
    if len(fruit_list) == 0:
        fruit_list = [(entered_fruit, num_pounds)]
    else:
        insert_index = 0
    index = 0
    location_found = False
    while index < len(fruit_list) and not location_found:
        if fruit_list[index][0] < entered_fruit:
            index = index + 1
        else:
            fruit_list.insert(index,(entered_fruit, num_pounds))
            location_found = True
        entered_fruit = input('\nEnter fruit: ')
print("the fruit List: ", fruit_list)
```

Could you please take a look to my code to let me know what's wrong with it?

Thank you all!

Comment: `I couldn't figure out how to sort and display as it shown in the question` What question?

Comment: when I added more than 4 items. the output is not be in the right way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One loop is enough:

```
fruits = []
while True:
    fruit = input('Input fruit name: ')
    weight = input('Input weight (pounds): ')
    fruits.append('{}, {} lbs'.format(fruit, weight))
    action = input('Do you want to add another fruit [y/n]? ').lower()
    if action == 'n':
        break

print('The fruit list: ')
for fruit in sorted(fruits):
    print(fruit)
```

Output:

```
Input fruit name: Banana
Input weight (pounds): 11
Do you want to add another fruit [y/n]? y
Input fruit name: Apple
Input weight (pounds): 6
Do you want to add another fruit [y/n]? n
The fruit list: 
Apple, 6 lbs
Banana, 11 lbs
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use `itemgetter`. Example:

```
from operator import itemgetter
fruit_list = [("Banana", 9), ("Peach", 7), ("Apple", 3)]
print(sorted(fruit_list, key=itemgetter(0)))
```

`itemgetter(0)` will get the first item which is the fruit name, so that you'll get the list sorted in alphabetical order.

Output:

```
[('Apple', 3), ('Banana', 9), ('Peach', 7)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This would help!
but I need the code to be with no built-in functions!